# Workflow Process - if all records are approved create new row

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query where I need to check if multiple records are in the same stage then I insert new one, if the records aren't in the same stage it should do nothing.

Example for the table records:

```
RecordID              StageID         
1                     3
1                     2
5                     3
7                     3
7                     3
```

When the RecordID has met the condition which is if multiple records are in the same stage Then It should insert new records like this

```
RecordID              StageID
5                     4
7                     4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a properly phrased `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` should work here.  The `SELECT` query below finds all records all of whose stages are the same, and returns the corresponding `RecordID` along with the current stage incremented by one.  Note that we can simply take the `MAX` (or `MIN`, or really any aggregate) here because all stage values would be the same for such matching records.

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (RecordID, StageID)
SELECT RecordID, MAX(StageID) + 1
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY RecordID
HAVING MIN(StageID) = MAX(StageID)
```

Comment: I prefer `MIN(StageID) = MAX(StageID)` because `COUNT(DISTINCT)` can have a lot of additional overhead.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Answer edited; I can imagine why `COUNT(DISTINCT)` might have a higher cost than just doing a `MIN` or `MAX` on a group of records.

Comment: `Having MIN(StageID) = MAX(StageID)` works fine in the case of the example. However, I have used  `HAVING COUNT(StageID) = 2 ` .. Thank you @TimBiegeleisen for the help